# Can a person fail in MBA?

Tags: masters

I am thinking about pursuing an MBA outside my home country (either UK, US, Canada or Australia) but a bit worried since my undergraduate degree is from a small university in a developing country and my GMAT is only 590.  I wonder if people can actually fail in MBA?

In an undergraduate study we know courses are sometimes sequenced (when you fail a course, it means you have to repeat it and are unable to take some other classes until you pass it), does it apply in MBA? Many MBA programs in Europe are only 1 year, if courses are sequenced and one fails it once in the 1st semester, doesn't it mean he will need at least 2 years to finish? And is there GPA in MBA?

Comment: See my comments in Matt's answer if interested ^-^

Answer (score 11):

Of course you can fail an MBA. Otherwise, you could enroll, never go to class, do no work, learn nothing, and still graduate. Sequenced courses will depend on the specific course of study you're enrolling in. Usually, you will be graded, meaning that you will have a GPA for your MBA studies.

Comment: I think OP is trying to ask if one can be removed from his/her program due to failing a class particularly one that is needed for many other classes (eg Ma101 rather than Ma104 in the subject chain Ma101 --> Ma102 --> Ma103 --> Ma104)

Comment: I think OP is also trying to ask about how heavy the prerequisites are. From what I've seen masteral studies never have a chain higher than 3 in any 1 program. I suspect OP's first language isn't English.